# how to put a drop down list and date selector in a flex advanced data grid

Tags: apache-flex, flash, drop-down-menu, advanceddatagrid

How can one put components into an advanced data grid?

I wish to have a standard row with string items except two items,
no 1 there is a date field and I need a date selector for it.
no 2 in another cell of the row I want to put a drop down list box containing text "40" and "20" or you can manually edit the cell so that it displays what ever input you decide (other than 40 and 20)

thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several examples on web, I don't want to do copy paste so I will post here two links:

combo box editor:http://blog.flexmonkeypatches.com/2008/02/18/simple-datagrid-combobox-as-item-editor-example/
http://groups.google.com/group/flex_india/msg/27a9133b0837e35a?pli=1

I'm sure that you can find many more samples using a search engine.